# My Ajax script not work with datatype json

Tags: json, ajax

In my codes, i could post data without error. but i cant return data from php file to show in my html tag. If i delete dataType: 'json', it works fine but as you know i cant get data. I get this error while datatype = json

```
error : {"readyState":4,"responseText":"<head>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n-1","status":200,"statusText":"parsererror"}
```

My ajax;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // like and unlike click
    $(".like, .unlike").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;   // Getting Button id
        var split_id = id.split("_");

        var text = split_id[0];
        var postid = split_id[1];  // postid

        // Finding click type
        var type = 0;
        if(text == "like"){
            type = 1;
        }else{
            type = 0;
        }

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'likeunlike.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {baslikid:postid,type:type},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var likes = data['likesonuc'];

                $("#sonuc_"+postid).text(likes);        // setting likes

                if(type == 1){
                    $("#like_"+postid).css("color","#ffa449");
                    $("#unlike_"+postid).css("color","lightseagreen");
                }

                if(type == 0){
                    $("#unlike_"+postid).css("color","#ffa449");
                    $("#like_"+postid).css("color","lightseagreen");
                }


            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("error : " + JSON.stringify(data));
            }

        });

    });

});
```

My php file(I didnt share above to avoid confusion. I get int result from $likesonuc)

```
$likesonuc= $total_likes - $total_unlikes;


echo json_encode($likesonuc);
```

Comment: sounds like your JSON is not valid. Look at the http request in the network panel. Does it have other markup being returned from your php?

Comment: This seems telling: `"responseText":"<head>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n-1"`  Using `dataType: 'json'` won't work if the data isn't JSON.

Comment: @epascarello i look network panel but nothing returned from my php file

Comment: Well the responseText in your message shows HTML Markup so it is returning something. You need to show your PHP file so someone can point out why it is returning html back.

Comment: Yes u are right, i deleted head tags. I dont get any error now but data as well. Could be something wrong in my ajax success part? Or is there any way to see what data come from php?

Comment: You are doing `data['likesonuc']` in your success handler, but the data is a JSON number, so it has no `likesonuc` property. If you want it to be an _object_ with that property, you'll have to send a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your response, you can see that the body you're returning from PHP:

```
<head>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n</head>\n-1
```

...is not JSON. It looks like you're writing out the head of the HTML somewhere and then the JSON number `-1`. You need to send *just* the JSON in your response or it can't be parsed as JSON.

Comment: Yes yes u are right. I deleted <head> from php. And now i dont get any error but data as well. If it is show no error that means i get the data but there is something in wrong after succes?

Comment: Check for errors in your browser's console or set breakpoints in the code so you can see what's happening.

Comment: I dont see any error in console. the rest of success is working but var likes = data['likesonuc']; is not. U said above. but how can i send a number with json

Comment: `data` _is_ the number.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you!